# Quiz: Top Three

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function, `top_three`, that takes a list as its argument, and returns a list of the three largest elements. 
For example

```
top_three([2,3,5,6,8,4,2,1]) == [8, 6, 5]
```

My code was:

```
def top_three(input_list):
input_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
a=sorted(input_list, reverse=True)
b=input_list[0:3]
return b
print(top_three(input_list))
```

Comment: You should not declare the input list inside your function, the way you did it, it is not even callable from the outside (so `print(top_three(input_list))` will give error).

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, but if you want to know why it doesn't work, the first and most obvious is that Python requires indentation. Describe your problem properly and make sure the code you post matches the code you are trying to execute.

Comment: thanks now i got it.....

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
input_list=[1,10,22,2,3,4,5]
def top_three(input_list):
    result = sorted(input_list, reverse=True)
    return result[0:3]
print(top_three(input_list))
```